# What are the conditions for a glow discharge to occur vs an electric arc to occur in a glass tube?

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity

After the invention of vacuum pumps, people experimented with running electricity in evacuated or partially evacuated glass tubes. In some sources people say this results in a [glow discharge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glow_discharge) and in other sources people say this results in a [electric arc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_arc). I've not been able to find the criteria that determine whether we'll have a glow discharge vs an electric arc.

I read over [this post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/116925), but I don't really understand it very well. Can someone explain the conditions for having a glow discharge vs electric arc in undergrad terms?

Answer (score 1):

This [website](https://www.plasma-universe.com/electric-glow-discharge/#Basic_Glow_Discharge_Structure) has a good discussion and has a  graph that shows the current voltage relationship for the different types of discharge.

In the glow discharge the plasma is self sustaining so the question to ask is what is happening to keep it going and why is there a constant voltage in the plasma region. There is a equilibrium where atoms are being knocked about, some hitting the cathode and ejecting more atom with energy and energy also being lost as excited atoms emit photons. In the glow region there is a relatively constant voltage that is relatively high. The glow discharge is at relatively low pressure.

In an arc you can also be in a sort of equilibrium, but you have broken down the gas into a plasma in a different way. It is a hot process, in fact the arc bows up in an ‘arc’ from the air being heated giving its name.  It doesn’t necessarily need to be at low pressure like a glow discharge, although that helps. And it is not so much the collision of energetic atoms hitting each other transferring energy. Instead as the air breaks down into a usually pretty narrow channel you have a large current of electrons.  So the question is where does the large current of electrons come from?
After the arc forms there is a big voltage drop and the plasma channel is acting more like a relatively low value resistor. And since the resistance is low you can get a lot of current. The electrons come from the electrode usually through the process of thermionic emission.

We like to think that the electrons would stay in a material. But if you think carefully about the surface there is a potential barrier that keeps the electrons in the material. As you increase the temperature eventually you will evaporate the material, but before that happens the temperature will give some of the electrons enough energy to leave the material. ( you could also try to pull electrons out of a material with a very large voltage in a process called field emission) but in this case it is high temperature that is giving the electrons energy to leave the electrons and travel through the plasma. Your power supply is also giving the electrode more electrons so it doesn’t charge up.